# How to persist selected checkboxes when using pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

In my MVC application, I have a ViewModel and it has checkboxes for each row. Ia'm also using pagination. Below is my code. If I select a few checkboxes on page 1 and then navigate to page 2 and select few more checkboxes. When I navigate back to page 1, the checkboxes previously selected are no longer selected. How do I persist the selected checkboxes when using pagination. Submit button is only clicked when I want to edit all selected checkboxes on all the pages.

Thanks

Here is my ViewModel,

```
public class TraineeSelectionViewModel
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditCommon", "Trainees", FormMethod.Post, new { 
encType = "multipart/form-data", name = "myform" }))
{
  <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Select
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id, page = Model.PageNumber }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id, page = Model.PageNumber })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="Submit" name="operation" id="submit" value="Edit Selected"
    class="btn btn-primary" />
 }

 <br />@ViewBag.PageNum
 Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of
 @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter =
ViewBag.CurrentFilter, SearchColumn = ViewBag.CurrentSearchColumn }))
```

And here is my controller,

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page)
 {
  var model = new TraineeSelectionViewModel();

  TotTrainees = from s in db.TraineeAdmins select s;

  List<TraineeSelectionViewModel> T = new List<TraineeSelectionViewModel>();

        foreach (var Trainee in TotTrainees)
        {
            var TraineeViewModel = new TraineeSelectionViewModel()
            {
                Selected = false,
                Id = Trainee.Id,
                FirstName = Trainee.FirstName,
                MiddleInitial = Trainee.MiddleInitial,
                LastName = Trainee.LastName
            };

            T.Add(TraineeViewModel);
        }

  int pageSize = 10;
  int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
  return View(T.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: You can handle the `.click()` event of your 'Page' buttons, and make an ajax call to submit the selected checkboxes to a server method which persists them somewhere

Comment: Can you give an example please.